# JMC: Total CPU usage is per core or overall

Tags: java, profiling, jmc

I'm using Java Mission Control released with jdk 7u40. Is "Total CPU Usage" is calculated per core or overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normalized, both in Flight Recorder and the JMX Console. Maximum is 100%

Answer (score 0):

Its overall. so if you have 4 cores it can go up to 400%

Please see the ans link [here as well](https://superuser.com/questions/457624/why-is-the-top-command-showing-a-cpu-usage-of-799)

Comment: But on JMC dashboard, CPU Usage dial still shows 100% as max. Does it mean values calculated with 400% base are converted to 100% base? http://imgur.com/vkcODCN